# SQL Server - How to get the average rating from another table and include it in current table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, calculated-columns

I have a table of contractors like so:

```
SELECT [ContractorID]
  ,[Contractor]
  ,[BWSLVendorCode]
  ,[PhoneNumber]
  ,[Address]
  ,[PreQualification]
  ,[GSTNumber]
  ,[Avg] FROM Contractor
```

And a Feedback table that stores individual rating and comments for each contractor like so:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[ContractorID]
  ,[Rating]
  ,[Comments]
  ,[Timestamp] FROM Feedback
```

What I want to do is find the average rating of each individual contractor and include it in the contractor table under the Avg column. I thought about using a function and calling it in a computed column, but I can't seem to figure out how to write said function.

**EDIT:**
The rating is between 1 - 5

Comment: What's the data type of Rating? Please show some sample data to help understanding,

Comment: Rating is int.
So if a contractor has a multiple ratings, I want to average these ratings and add it to the Contractor table under Avg for that particular contractor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will update the `Avg` column in the `Contractor` table with the average value of ratings of the contractor in the `Feedback` table.

```
;with feedback_grouped 
AS 
( 
SELECT f.ContractorID, AVG(CAST(f.rating as decimal(3,2))) as avg_rating
   FROM   Feedback f
   GROUP BY f.ContractorID
)
UPDATE Contractor
SET avg=avg_rating
FROM Contractor c
INNER JOIN feedback_grouped 
ON c.ContractorID = feedback_grouped.ContractorID
```

This groups each feedback by `ContractorID` and calculates the average `Rating` to update the original `Contractor` table

Ensure that the `Avg` column in `Contractor` table is a `decimal` datatype since the average might have decimal values. You can change the `(CAST(f.rating as decimal(3,2)))` to the same decimal datatype you are using in the `Avg` column.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

To automatically update the column value, you can use a trigger, which would look something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBName].[updateAvg]
ON [DBName].Contractors
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS
BEGIN   

;WITH avgRates AS (
SELECT [ContractorID]
  ,SUM([Rating]) as totalRating
  ,COUNT(*) as noOfRatings
FROM Feedback
GROUP BY ContractorID
        )

UPDATE C
SET Avg = A.totalRating / A.noOfRatings
FROM Contractor C
INNER JOIN avgRates A
ON C.ContractorID = A.ContractorID

END
```

My syntax may be wrong on the `CREATE TRIGGER`, so you would want to reference the official documentation:

[CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: How would this add the average in the Avg column of my Contractors table?

Comment: This wouldn't change the actual stored value in the table, but you could run this as a view, or you could start by writing deleting and repopulating Contractors. You would have to do it manually, or you could set up a trigger to refresh the column every time the table gets updated.

Comment: A trigger is another option, if you don't mind, how would I be able to write that trigger?

Answer (score 0):

How many "Contractors" are you expecting in your database?  And how many Feedbacks per contractor?  I ask this because calculating the Avg should be done at runtime so that you don't have to recalculate every time a new feedback is put in...

Instead of saving the Avg in the table, maybe you should have a view that calculates that and call the view instead of the table.  Such as like this:

`CREATE VIEW ContractorView AS
  SELECT C.*, 
    ((SELECT SUM(F1.Rating) FROM Feedback as F1 WHERE F1.ContractorID = C.ContractorID) / (SELECT COUNT(F2.ID) FROM Feedback as F2 WHERE F2.ContractorID = C.ContractorID)) as Avg
  FROM Contractors as C`

The syntax is something close to that. ;)

Comment: (Forgot to put that the rating is between 1 and 5) The number of contractors and feedback associated with contractors is not restricted. It could go up to the 100s. I see what you're saying however for me to include the average in a table is easiest for me because I reflect the table in a front end web application. I would prefer not to calculate everytime the page is open either, I'd prefer to have that be done in the database.

Comment: This would be done on the database... a view is calculated in the database.  A proper data-access-layer will see the view as a "table".  So you would access it on the front-end just like a table.

Comment: Yes, but I access the Contractor's table because I do different tasks such as UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE from the Contractors table as well. If I use a view then I would have to reference both tables at the front end and I'm trying to avoid to make my SELECT statement more complicated for development reasons

Comment: If that is a hard rule you are enforcing, the other option would be to add triggers to your database so that when an feedback item is Created/Updated/Deleted, then you recalculate the Avg for all the contractors...